# Flutter Circular Progress Indicator Using Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I Want to use my App icon during the loading. How it can be implemented. Currently I am using Circular Progress Indicator.

```
return Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(
               strokeWidth: 2));
```

Answer (score 7):

If all you want is simple progress indicator you can use this

```dart
class ProgressWithIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProgressWithIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            // you can replace this with Image.asset
            'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1393171?s=50&v=4',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
          ),
          // you can replace
          const CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
            strokeWidth: 0.7,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

But if you are looking for something complex I will suggest you to go with

- [rive](https://rive.app/) [package](https://pub.dev/packages/rive)
- [lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/) [package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)

Answer (score 0):

There various ways of implementing custom loaders. If your loader is animated then know the extension format of your loader. In my experience using a json animated loader like one with https://lottiefiles.com/ is using a package called lottie
`dependencies: lottie: ^1.2.1`
If your loader is a plain image then you have an option to use a timer to display the image before an action is taken for instance await for some data from the internet.
*Let me know if you need more assistance*